# Quorum: "read error invalid character 'P' looking for beginning of value" on private transaction

Tags: quorum

Quorum over Ubuntu 16.04, Geth 1.7.2-stable.

Quorum is installed and it passes the tests. 3 nodes (all roles enabled) with their corresponding constellations. Tested both over 3 local docker containers and over 3 remote virtual machines.

Ethereum regular transactions work properly. But, when trying to perform private transactions by adding the *privateFor* field, I get:

> TRACE[02-08|16:37:15] Dial task done                           task="discovery lookup"
>
> TRACE[02-08|16:37:15] New dial task                            task="discovery lookup"
>
> INFO [02-08|16:37:18] sending private tx                       data= privatefrom= privatefor="[Hniwqqpw1SE0BDpxAhp7w0Q6NLMCh4x77xA83iM6amk=]"
>
> DEBUG[02-08|16:37:18] read error invalid character 'P' looking for beginning of value
>
> INFO [02-08|16:37:18] sent private tx                          data= privatefrom= privatefor="[Hniwqqpw1SE0BDpxAhp7w0Q6NLMCh4x77xA83iM6amk=]"

That was the simplest attempt. I have also tried to upload an smart contract, etc.

The error comes from line 97 of https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/blob/master/private/constellation/node.go (*c.httpClient.Do(req)*) and the 'P' character is the 'P' from 'POST', the method name. GET method causes a *invalid character 'G'*.

It looks a little weird to me. It is probably related to my configuration and not Quorum itself, but I have checked all the steps and some existing examples and rebuilt Quorum after inserting more log messages and I cannot find the problem.

Any suggestion about my issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault.

By accident (a bad configuration) both sockets (the one from the geth node and the one from the constellation) were trying to use the same IPC socket file.